# NSOperation with repeat option

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, nsoperation

I've developed a Category that gives the NSOperation the ability to be executed in the background at timed intervals. I would really appreciate getting some feedback on this, especially any potential problems with this approach that I'm not thinking of.

Thank you!

Here's the code:

NSOperation+Repeat.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSOperation (repeat)

@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSTimeInterval repeatInterval;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSOperationQueue *repeatOperationQueue;

- (void)performUsingOperationQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)operationQueue;
- (void)performAtRepeatingInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval usingOperationQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)operationQueue;

@end
```

NSOperation+Repeat.m

```
#import "NSOperation+repeat.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static char const * const RepeatPropertiesKey = "RepeatProperties";

@implementation NSOperation (repeat)

@dynamic repeatInterval;
@dynamic repeatOperationQueue;

static NSString * RepeatIntervalKey = @"interval";
static NSString * RepeatOperationQueueKey = @"operationQueue";
static NSString * RepeatTimerKey = @"timer";

- (NSMutableDictionary *)repeatProperties {
    NSMutableDictionary * properties = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, RepeatPropertiesKey);
    if (properties == nil) {
        properties = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, RepeatPropertiesKey, properties, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    }
    return properties;
}

- (NSTimeInterval)interval {
    NSNumber * interval = [[self repeatProperties] objectForKey:RepeatIntervalKey];
    return [interval doubleValue];
}

- (NSOperationQueue *)repeatOperationQueue {
    NSOperationQueue * operationQueue = [[self repeatProperties] objectForKey:RepeatOperationQueueKey];
    return operationQueue;
}

- (void)performUsingOperationQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)operationQueue {
    [operationQueue addOperation:[self copy]];
}

- (void)performAtInterval:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self performUsingOperationQueue:self.repeatOperationQueue];
}

- (void)performAtRepeatingInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval usingOperationQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)operationQueue {
    // Save interval and operationQueue in repeatProperties
    [self.repeatProperties setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:interval] forKey:RepeatIntervalKey];
    [self.repeatProperties setValue:operationQueue forKey:RepeatOperationQueueKey];

    // Create timer to call performAtInterval on self
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(interval*60)
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(performAtInterval:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];

    // Save the timer in repeatProperties
    [self.repeatProperties setValue:timer forKey:RepeatTimerKey];

    [self performUsingOperationQueue:operationQueue];
}

@end
```

Here's an example of a NSOperation subclass that can repeat:

MSScheduleImportOperation.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NSOperation+Repeat.h"

@interface MSScheduleImportOperation : NSOperation <NSCopying>

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSString* employeeId;

- (id)initWithEmployeeId:(NSString *)employeeId;

@end
```

MSScheduleImportOperation.m

```
#import "MSScheduleImportOperation.h"

@implementation MSScheduleImportOperation

@synthesize employeeId = __employeeId;

- (id)initWithEmployeeId:(NSString *)employeeId     {
    self = [super init];
    __employeeId = [employeeId copy];
    return self;
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    MSScheduleImportOperation* copy = [[MSScheduleImportOperation alloc] initWithEmployeeId:self.employeeId];
    return copy;
}

- (void)main
{
 ...   
}


@end
```

Comment: I can see quite a few issues. First of all, you are making a copy of the NSOperation which I'm guessing most subclasses do not support.

Secondly, you don't seem to handle cancellation. If an operation is cancelled then this code will continue to spawn off more instances.

Thirdly, if an operation takes a long time to complete, this code will spawn up more instances and you will have multiple operations running at the same time.

Comment: Yes, the subclass of NSOperation must be defined with the NSCopying protocol and implement the (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone.

Comment: On the cancellation, I need to add that. I should be able to just assign nil to the timer to make it stop repeating.

Comment: On the long running operation creating a situation where an operation is started before the previous one completes - yes, definitely a possibility. Any suggestion on how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) says:

> An operation object is a single-shot object—that is, it executes its task once and cannot be used to execute it again.

So the first problem is that there might be internals that stop it from working.  Although, I see you try to get around the problem by making a copy.

This leads us to the other problem is that `NSOperation` is not advertised to conform to `NSCopying`.

```
[operationQueue addOperation:[self copy]];
```

This line should throw an exception.

Comment: Yes, with the copying of the NSOperation subclass I was trying to address the one-shot aspect of the NSOperation class. It does seem to be working though. My subclass is defined with the NSCopying protocol and implements  (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone. I guess the worry would be what properties of NSOperation are not getting deep-copied. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a category on `NSOperation` where the object copies itself and adds the copy to an `NSOperationQueue` - it would be simpler to manage this at a higher level. For example:

```
+[RepeatingOperation operationBlock:(InitOperationBlock)operationBlock
                              queue:(NSOperationQueue*)queue
                           interval:(NSTimeInterval)interval];
```

where `InitOperationBlock` would be a block where the operation was created and configured.

The main benefit is the API would be harder to mess up. For example in category in the original post, `performUsingOperationQueue:` will fail silently if you forget to set `repeatOperationQueue`.